# What is the difference between global and local navigation in sharepoint 2013

Tags: quick-launch, top-link-bar, global-navigation, current-navigation

I want to understand what's the difference between global navigation and local navigation in sharepoint 2013.
or i can say what are the features of top link bar and global navigation in sharepoint 2013?

What are the pros and cons of both the navigation types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global navigation refers to the top navigation which is there at the top side on your page, and local navigation is on the left side of the page. Local navigation is as per the content of your local site.

Ref: [Article](http://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-navigation-best-practices/)